# How to print result in Elixir anonymous function

Tags: elixir, mnesia

What I want to do to is to get the record count in remote node where the record has the begining equal to <<'*fb'>>. Here is my code, however, it does not return the result. Instead, it just return the process id #PID<10878.11003.0>. How can I make it return the record count?

```
Node.spawn :'abc@abc.com', sum = fn ->
  for n <- :mnesia.dirty_select(:'cz_jid_mapping',[{{:cz_jid_mapping, :'$1', :'_',:'_',:'_'},[],[:'$1']}]) do
    io.format((binary_part(n,0,3)==<<"*fb">>))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spawned process runs concurrently. Thus, if you want to send something to the caller process, you need to use messages:

```
me = self

Node.spawn :'abc@abc.com', sum = fn ->
  result = ...
  send(me, {:result, result})
end

receive do
  {:result, result} -> {:ok, result}
after timeout_in_ms -> {:error, :timeout}
end
```

However, this is a lot of boilerplate, and using `Node.spawn/2` should be avoided in production, since it may fail if different nodes don't have exactly the same version of the module.

It's better to implement and export some function that does the job on a local node, for example `Db.record_count`. Then, you can use services from the [`:rpc`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rpc.html) module to invoke that function on some other node. In particular, `:rpc.call` will invoke the function and return the result:

```
:rpc.call(:foo@bar, Db, :record_count, [arg1, arg2, ...], timeout_in_ms)
```